# How can i find the size of a dynamically allocated array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, size, sizeof, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've made an array that is dynamically allocated by a cycle. And then a cycle that reads the numbers out of the array but i need to know the size of the array. The array is correct and fully working and has correct values in it.
I defined the array like this:

```
int *array;
```

Now when i want to use this it wont work because im using a pointer:

```
int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
```

How can i fix it so it works with my pointer?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are allocating the array using one of new or malloc/calloc.  In that case, you can't do this.  You need to track the size in another variable or use a structure that will track the size for you.

Comment: Yes i used malloc, I was thinking about placing a variable like 0 and then run a cycle until it finds the 0. Although it will work, i was aiming for leaving the array free of these identifiers. But thanks :)