# How can I retrieve the size of a smart pointer array? (e..g std::unique_ptr<int[]>)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Heap-allocated c arrays don't retain any size information, as pointed out here:

[How can i find the size of a dynamically allocated array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594935/how-can-i-find-the-size-of-a-dynamically-allocated-array-in-c)

However, smart pointers in c++11 have the ability to store memory and manage c-arrays with the array versions using the subscript (`[]`) operator overload:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr(new int[val]);
```

When this smart pointer goes out of scope, it presumably deallocates the owned block of memory, so it must store the *size* of the memory block somewhere.

How can I retrieve the size of the c array allocated on `arr` in the above example, assuming that `val` is a runtime variable?

Comment: `malloc_size` may be useful. but you really just need `std::vector`

Comment: Why do you need dynamic allocation for array with statically defined size? I think that `std::array` is better for your case (or `std::vector` for really dynamic arrays).

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` is really more of a last resort if you can't use a vector.

Comment: @myaut it's not statically defined.

Comment: @chris I could use a vector, but it would be misleading to the reader because the size never changes, but is only known at runtime. `std::vector` would certainly do the job though, but I'm reluctant to use it because I want the intent to be as clear as possible. Also, the size only needs to be known for debug asserts, so using a different container just so I can run asserts isn't great practice.

Comment: @quant for such cases C++14 introduced `std::dynarray` but it seems that it was excluded from final version of standard.

Comment: @quant If I were your reader I would think: Why the heck did he use that contraption instead of `std::vector`? `smart_ptr<T[]>` is really more of a bad idea than anything else. Even the `boost::shared_array` documentation states that `shared_ptr<vector>` is a worthy alternative.

Comment: @myaut `dynarray` was invented to bridge the gap to `C99/C11`. But no one really knows how to really design such a thing and so it got dropped again.

Comment: @pmr it's a specific implementation for a specific use case and it's in the standard. It provides clarity of intent not to modify the container, so in this case *less is more*. Why would I forego clarity for the sake of using a more robust container when I don't need its features? I don't think your argument makes sense.

Comment: @quant main problem with your approach is that you mixing C-style arrays (which lose size information) with C++11 smart pointers. Mixing C++ subsets is bad. Also deleting array will require `delete[]` so you will need to define custom deleter for unique pointer.

Comment: @quant I don't think there is much arguing when talking about readability and you probably know your audience better than me. 1) there is no use case for `smart_ptr<T[]>` that is not covered by `vector`, 2) just because it is in the standard means nothing (`auto_ptr`, `valarray`), 3) like I said: I don't think this adds clarity, it takes it away. And you obviously already have a case where you require a bell and whistle: getting the size.

Comment: @maut *you will need to define custom deleter for unique pointer* - this is incorrect, take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr#Array_version.2C_unique_ptr.3CT.5B.5D.3E

Comment: @pmr there is also no use case for `std::unique_ptr` that is not covered by `std::shared_ptr`...

Comment: @pmr regarding the other points. I only need the `size` method for debug asserts, so I don't want to change container on that basis alone, and you're right about the standard not always being ideal of course.

Comment: @quant Please. You are smart. You know this is not true. We need a smart pointer that does not come with the cost of thread-safe reference counting. So are you going to drop the debug assertions because you don't want to use `vector`? That would be really odd. I don't think we should continue this discussion here and I think I have made my point.

Comment: @pmr Yeah I agree on all points. I changed it to a vector.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With both `new[]`/`delete[]` and `malloc`/`free`, the size is indeed stored somewhere, but there is no standardized way to access that information.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I was hoping something along the lines of `sizeof(arr)` might work...